# Javascript refresh page

Tags: javascript

I have a html page with a button pop-up. If I click on this button a new window Pops-up, I do all of my changes in this window and then click the close button. The html page with the popup button should refresh after I closed the pop-up window. Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

yes.

```
//reload opener...
window.opener.location.reload();
//close self...
window.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<body onunload="opener.location.reload(true);">
```

Comment: Only thing to note here is that this will refresh the opening window ANY time the body is unloaded (this includes refreshes).

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>function reload(){document.location = document.location}</script>
```

Comment: This script would reload "this" page, not the opener... or are you suggesting to inject this in the opener when closing the popup?

Comment: sorry i wasn't paying attention didnt see he wanted to refresh opener...
id use my function above on opener page and make the call from popup
<body onunload="opener.reload();">

just another way to do it... that would work right?

Comment: If you have a hash in your URL it wont actually refresh the page, but just do whatever going to that hash does.